# Why in normed vector spaces we can define infinite series but in metric space we can not?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

We usually define infinite series by partial sums and an inifinite series is said to converge if its partial sum converges.

So, if $X$ is a **normed** vector spaces and $s_n=x_1+...+x_m$ is a partial sum then infinite series converges to s if
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}||s-s_n||=0.
\end{align}

My question why can't the same be done in vector **metric** spaces?
We can still define converges as
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}d(s,s_n)=0
\end{align}

Certainly when a metric is induced by a norm this is not a problem. But why is it a problem in the case when metric can not be defined by a norm?

Comment: Do you have a source saying this can't be done?

Comment: For example, in Kreyszig the author waits and introduces convergens of infinite series until he defines normed spaces.  My guess is because one can not define d absolute converegence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this. In fact, people even consider [topological vector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space).

Comment: Thanks. You see, I thought the reason was because absolute converges can not be defined.